# Write a javascript Array to a json file on another domain

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

First of all i have the following to convert my Javascript array to a JSON array.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js"></script>

  var sv_defaultArray = new Array([]);
  sv_defaultArray[0] = "post 4";
  sv_defaultArray[1] = "post 5";
  sv_defaultArray[2] = "post 6";

  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(sv_defaultArray);
```

Now i would like to write the converted array to a json file lets say http://www.foobar.com/array.json via any conventional method possible.

So now i am at the following stage with php and jQuery.post facilities;

```
<?php
$list = $_POST["array"];
$fp = fopen('array.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $list);
fclose($fp);
?>

$.post("http://www.foobar.com/write.php", { 'array': myJsonString});
```

The above solution is giving me errors mainly returned in console as origin errors.

Comment: which force do you believe should write that data on the target machine ? That needs to invoke some kind of server-logic obviously.

Comment: i was writing an array via php before as a CSV string, so php potentially ?

Comment: yes, any server script will potentially do it. You only need to surf around the same-origin policy barrier. Since we're talking about JSON, `json-padding` seems appropriate.

Comment: do you have any resources i could consult for writing the php code?  Essentially i am just using php to read the json array as a text string and then write the text string as is to the .json file?

Comment: @jAndy — since we're talking about writing data to the server, and since JSONP is limited to GET requests, it doesn't seem appropriate to me.

Comment: @Xavier: Exactly. It should be even easier than writing an array as CSV file.

Comment: im actually getting the data in a jsonp format.

Comment: updated the code above !

Comment: I think you cannot use Ajax to make a POST request to a different domain. You could, as already said, use JSONP. That has the disadvantage that the data you want to send is limited by the maximum length of a URL. You can create a form inside a hidden iframe and make the POST request through that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a server side PHP file on the other domain accept your json as POST/GET paramter, and write it to a file, then return a json response as result.

Then you can use jquery.getJSON on your first domain to call the url with your json that needs to be written

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

You need a server-side script that can write a file. Then you could send the json array to it through ajax and it will write the file.
I must stress the fact that javascript doesn't have access to the file-sistem, so it cannot be done with only pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to submit the data through a form as AJAX does not allow cross-domain requests. Everything else you are doing is 100% correct (assuming the php is on the destination server). I would recommend a text area with visibility:none style tag set. Use js to populate the textarea and submit the form using form.submit()